# Most Recent Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a schema that looks like this.
[image]

Using the recordings table , query the most recent data in the database for each entityid/accid/month combination (Main Table is the main table)

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
    select *,row_number() over(partition by entid, accid, month order by timestamp desc) as rn 
    from recordings a inner join maintable b on a.logid=b.logid
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
  select * from 
    (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by acctid,entid,month order by timestamp desc) rn
    from maintable m join racordings r on m.logid=r.logid
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select * from 
    (select m.*, r.*, e.*, a.*, row_number() over(partition by a.AcctID, e.EntID, Month order by r.TimeStamp desc) row_num
        from maintable m 
        inner join racordings r on m.LogID = r.LogID
        inner join Entities e on e.EntID = m.EntID
        inner join AccInfo a on a.AcctID = m.AcctID
    ) t1 
where t1.row_num = 1
```